# Given the Function Name, how to find the Changelist in perforce when that function was added?

Tags: perforce

I am looking for a way to find the changelist in perforce if I have the Function name and File in which that function is present ?
For Eg: if "A.cpp" has function added "void b()" via changelist 1234

I would like to get back changelist 1234 by giving the Function name only or both function name and file name. I was thinking to use python script for this but not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `p4 annotate`, e.g.:

```
p4 annotate -c A.cpp | grep "void b()"
```

Check out `p4 help annotate` for the options available -- you can use the `-I` flag to find the origin changelist if the line was added by a merge, you can use the `-a` flag to find text in earlier versions of the file, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Samwise, This is solving what I am looking for but only in case when changelist is submitted directly to that branch. What if functions reached my branch via integration and original CL is in another branch.

Comment: Check out `p4 help annotate` for the options available -- you can use the `-I` flag to find the origin changelist if the line was added by a merge.

Comment: Thanks A lot Samwise. Working Perfectly.

Comment: one more Query, I was wondering if i can run annotate directly in Depot instead syncing my branch in workspace. Is that possible ?

Comment: I am using the code as below:

>p4.run("annotate", '-I', 'DEPOT PATH | grep FUNCTION NAME')

getting the following error:

 >'[warning]: file(s) not in client view.''

Comment: You need to specify a valid depot path.  Sounds like you're specifying a local path that's not in your client view.